# VSCode can only attach to devtools background page in electron

Tags: typescript, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm attempting to debug the render process in an electron application using typescript, webpack, and react. On similar projects, when launched, a dropdown would appear when the debugger attaches to electron to select a page. This does not happen in this case. If I attempt to set `"url": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/index.html"` in launch.json I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tl4f.png):

`Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Can't find a valid target that matches {path}. Available pages: {vue dev tools page})`

Leaving `"url":` out results in the debugger attaching to the vue dev tools page (verified by `.scripts`).

The react page is displayed in electron and I can use devtools in electron to debug, and the source maps are there and working properly.

The folder structure is:

```
/dist/
    electron.js
    electron.js.map
    index.html
    react.js
    react.js.map
/src/
    /main/
        electron.ts
    /render/
        App.tsx
    index.html
```

And everyone's favorite, launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron: Main",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/electron.js",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/electron.js",
                ".",
                "--remote-debugging-port=4040",
            ],
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/*"],
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Electron: Renderer",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 4040,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/../*"
            },
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
            "timeout": 10000,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "trace": "verbose",
            "url": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/index.html"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Electron: All",
            "configurations": [
                "Electron: Main",
                "Electron: Renderer"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [
    {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: './src/render/App.tsx',
        target: 'electron-renderer',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: [
                '.tsx', '.ts,', '.js', '.css'
            ]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                include: /src/,
                use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }]
            }, {
                    test: /\.css$/i,
                    use: [
                        "style-loader",
                        "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: { modules: true }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: 'react.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './src/index.html'
            })
        ]
    },
    {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: './src/main/electron.ts',
        target: 'electron-main',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                include: /src/,
                use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }]
            }]
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: 'electron.js'
        }
    }
];
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strict": false,
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "baseUrl": "./"
    }
}
```

*Edit:* Some of the options launch.json, webpack.config.js, and tsconfig.json might be a bit wonky because I've been messing around with them for a while trying to get this to work and I'm not particularly fastidious about changing them back.

*Edit #2:*: I used trace to inspect the traffic between vscode and electron and was able to set the `"url: "` by copy and pasting the absolute path from one of the messages. This solves the problem of not being able to debug, but I still do not know why the dropdown does not appear, nor why using `"${workspaceFolder}/dist/index.html"` does not work, because as far as I can tell they should point to the same thing.